# What will happen to Linux pipe() if one end closes before other

Tags: linux, operating-system, pipe

I doing Inter process communication via pipe() syscall. The child writes to one end and parent is supposed to read other end of pipe.

The parent before starting to read, waitpid() for the child to finish completion. If child exited with non-zero return value -- then it indicates that child had errors. So parent simply closes the pipe descriptor and moves on without reading.

Do u think this will work in case of successful completion of child. The parent is effectively reaping the child before reading the pipe? If yes, then what will happen to data that is in transit? The OS will take care of data safely reaching the parent end?

Answer (score 3):

Parent process opens a pipe. Two pointers in the PDT will point to the pipe. One to the writing and one to the reading.

Whenever a child process is created using fork, the PDT is duplicated. Hence, the child process will have its own pointers in PDT pointing to the PIPE.

At first, the pipe is empty, if parent process tries to read, it will block.
And you will never create a child process. This will end up in a deadlock.

If you close the writing end before reading, you won't have deadlock, but then the child process won't be able to write to the pipe (read above why).

So this should be your flow:

```
1. Parent process creates pipe
2. fork()
3. in parent process you close the writing end
4. in child process you close the reading end
5. read/write to pipe.
```